# TestNG - @Factory & @DataProvider are not running when extending the class

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Here, the expectation is to run the @Factory & @DataProvider methods, when the class is extended.

The below example uses Factory & DataProvider annotations and is working as expected.

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataProviderFactory {

    protected String name;

    public DataProviderFactory() {
        super();
    }

    @Factory(dataProvider = "dp")
    public DataProviderFactory(String name) {
        System.out.println("Inside Factory");
        this.name = name;
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "dp")
    public Object[][] dataProvider() {
        System.out.println("Inside Data Provider");
        return new Object[][] {
            {"Data1"}, {"Data2"}
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Method 1: " + name);
    }

    @Test
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Method 2: " + name);
    }
}
```

The Output for the above is expected.

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
Inside Data Provider
Inside Factory
Inside Factory
Method 1: Data1
Method 1: Data2
Method 2: Data1
Method 2: Data2
```

Here, the above class is extended as below.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DataProviderFactoryTest extends DataProviderFactory {

    private String name;

    public DataProviderFactoryTest() {
        super();
    }

    public DataProviderFactoryTest(String name) {
        super(name);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Test
    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("Method 3: " + name);

    }
}
```

The Output for the above is:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
Method 1: null
Method 2: null
Method 3: null
```

**Expected Output:**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
Inside Data Provider
Inside Factory
Inside Factory
Inside Factory
Method 1: Data1
Method 1: Data2
Method 2: Data1
Method 2: Data2
Method 3: Data1
Method 3: Data2
```

Please let me know how to handle this.

Comment: You can add the @Factory-Annotation to the constructor of the derived class.

Comment: Yes, the said solution works out. Is there any other way without having to specify Factory annotation to the constructor of the derived class?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in your test code.

- Since you added a default no argument constructor, TestNG is invoking that and that explains the null values.
- Lets say you removed it and just left the 1 argument constructor, TestNG would still invoke it by passing the current `<test>` tag's name (That's how TestNG works).
- TestNG doesn't have visibility to base class constructors that are annotated using the `@Factory` annotations, because AFAIK annotations aren't inherited

So the fix would be to explicitly add the `@Factory` annotation on top of each constructor that you want to work as a factory method for producing test class instances.